# x^2 congruencies

Tags: discrete-mathematics, congruences

I have $ \mathsf x^2 \equiv 1 mod 15 $
They first i thought was, why don't we check which x are congruent to 1? So i replace x with numbers from 0 to 14; after that, i see that

$ \mathsf 1^2 \equiv 1 (15) $

$ \mathsf 4^2 \equiv 1 (15) $

$ \mathsf 11^2 \equiv 1 (15) $

$ \mathsf 14^2 \equiv 1 (15) $

But then i don't know how to proceed. I need to have 4 cases where:

$ \mathsf x \equiv 1 (5) $

$ \mathsf x \equiv 1 (3) $

(in sistem)

$ \mathsf x \equiv 1 (5) $

$ \mathsf x \equiv -1 (3) $

(in sistem)

$ \mathsf x \equiv -1 (5) $

$ \mathsf x \equiv 1 (3) $

(in system)

$ \mathsf x \equiv -1 (5) $

$ \mathsf x \equiv -1 (3) $

in sistem

I'd really like an overall explanation of the whole procedure tho, would be helpful!

Comment: These problems can produce some interesting counts.  Consider the application of the Chinese Remainder Theorem, since $15=3\cdot 5$.

Comment: Yeah but where do -1 comes from?

Comment: What's the problem?  For example, $11 \equiv -1 \mod 3$ and $\equiv 1 \mod 5$.

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html

Comment: Another way: Clearly if $y$ is a solution, so will be $-y$. Now $$x^2\equiv1\implies(x,15)=\implies$$ we need to check for  $$x\equiv1,2,4,7$$